# modify read access in system tables for access 2007

Tags: database, oracle, ms-access, permissions

So i am attempting to open an mdb file in oracle sql developer, however i am getting this error:

```
No read access to system tables. modify access db before retrying.
```

I understand that this means i need to go into the system tables in access and modify them to be able to be read by oracle. I've found an article on how to do this, but it seems to be for access 2003...I've included the [link](http://www.packtpub.com/article/ms-access-queries-with-oracle-sql-developer-one-point-two-tool) incase anyone ever needs it.

What i would like to know is how to go about viewing the system tables and then changing permission in access2007?

Any help of suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You are trying to read the MS Access MSYS* tables, yesno? If so, why?

Comment: Gotta love finding the answer to your question not 5 mins after posting it... i figured i would post the [link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-access/access-2007-migration-export-errors-error-3021/05f73b61-e5ff-466b-8c80-6d3b98f52f94) of what you have to do to solve this problem in case anyone else has this same problem.

Comment: @James213 you should post your solution as an answer to your question. and then accept the answer. Then it is be obvious to others with the same problem what the answer is. :)

Comment: @bluefeet, i was planning to, but i guess there is a rule that says you cannot answer your own question until 7 hours after it has been posted. i will add it now though thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gotta love finding the answer to your question immediatly after posting it....

I figure this may be a problem for other people so i figured i would post the solution for others.

1. Open your database in Access 2007.
2. Click the "Office button" in the upper left-hand corner and "Access Options" from the pop-up.
3. Click on "Current Database".
4. In the "Navigation" section, click on the "Navigation Options..." button.
5. In the lower left-hand corner of the "Navigation Options" pane, make sure "Show System Objects" is checked; then click "OK".
6. Click "OK" on the "Access Options" pane.
7. On the ribbon, click "Database Tools", then "Users and Permissions", then "User and Group Permissions".
8. In the "User/Group Name" window select "Admin" (if it is not already selected); then scroll the "Object Name" window until you come to the "MSysXXX" objects. Some of these already have "Permissions" boxes checked; leave them alone. Check the "Read Data" box for the others.

here is the [link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-access/access-2007-migration-export-errors-error-3021/05f73b61-e5ff-466b-8c80-6d3b98f52f94) to where i found the answer....

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary in a default Access database. It should only be required if permissions have been altered, and in that case, it's likely someone was attempting to secure the database with Jet user-level security. In that case, you just need the username/password pair that has the necessary permissions (in a secured database, the admin user has its permissions removed). In short, you've likely undone something that someone else did for a reason, and you've just opened up the database to everybody (i.e., you've removed any security).